# Replicating javascript search in scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm not having success in scraping this website because it's does not contain any forms.

My crawler always returns nothing when I dump response data to a file:

```
  import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mamega.org'
    start_urls = ['https://www.mamega.org/search/']
    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.Request('https://www.mamega.org/_searchm.php',
                                method="POST",
                                meta = {'section': 'ebooks', 'datafill': 'musso'},
                                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}, 
                                callback = self.after_login
                                )



    def after_login(self, response):
        print ("__________________________________________after_login______________________________________________________")
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
           f.write(response.body)
           self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
        for title in response.xpath('//table[@style="width:93%;"]//tbody//tr//td/following-sibling::a[2]/@href'):
            yield {'roman': title.css('a ::text').extract_first(),'url': title.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first POST request doesn't contain any body.

If you take a look at the website you can see it includes 3 things that you need to replicate to get a proper response from their server:

[image]

The `content-type` and `x-requested-with` headers and some `form data` type body.

You can replicate this in your crawler:

```
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest' 
}
Request(
    'https://www.mamega.org/_searchm.php', 
    method='POST', 
    body='section=ebooks&datafill=musso', 
    headers=headers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return scrapy.Request('https://www.mamega.org/_searchm.php',
                                method="POST",
                                meta = {'section': 'ebooks', 'datafill': 'musso'},
                                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}, 
                                callback = self.after_login
                                )
```

data you are passing as meta is actually `formdata` of `POST` Request.

Make Your Request as:

```
return scrapy.Request('https://www.mamega.org/_searchm.php',
                                method="POST",
          #formdata             formdata = {'section': 'ebooks', 'datafill': 'musso'},
                                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}, 
                                callback = self.after_login
                                )
```